# Lens or arrows for updating a tree structures?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, arrows

I ran into an example (from 2010) of [using arrows for XML manipulation](https://github.com/silkapp/xml-arrow/blob/master/examples/Test.hs)

Are there advantages to `arrow` abstraction over more recent `lens` for use-case demonstrated there?

Answer (score 3):

[Lenses and arrows are theoretical cousins](http://twanvl.nl/tag/lens), both attempts to create compositional, functional values that could act as both getters and setters. But, and this is a subjective opinion, I think that if you're on the fence you should use lens. It comes down to library support. Lens is

- More actively maintained, with commits landing almost every day
- Basically the same user interface (use `.` to smash lenses together to form new lenses vs. use `.` to smash arrows together)
- Possible to [lift arrows into lenses](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/1nwetz/lenses_that_work_with_arrows/ccmrn33) (sort of; more of a demonstration than anything)
- Possible to [lens into XML with xml-lenses](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml-lens-0.1.6.3/docs/Text-XML-Lens.html)
- Filled with other goodies (like traversals and folds and isomorphisms) and helpers (think: lensing into generics, uniplate, MonadReader/MonadState)
- Currently more popular in the Haskell community, with e.g. more people knowledgable and answering questions on Stack Overflow

One downside: `lens` is a big ol' package with gnarly types.

Comment: I think it's quite a stretch to say arrows are about being able to act both as a getter and a setter.

Comment: just the arrows in twanvl's blog post

Comment: first link in the answer

Comment: The first link says nothing about arrows.

Comment: 'references, arrows, and categories'